# convert string elements in list as integers in python

Tags: string, list, int

I have a list named newlist

```
newlist=[['24,4,17,46,0,43'], ['11,43,17'], ['33,17,43,4'], ['74,21'],['21,43,43,74,68,21']]
```

I need to convert each list element as integers.i.e.

```
newlist=[[24,4,17,46,0,43], [11,43,17], [33,17,43,4], [74,21], [21,43,43,74,68,21]].
```

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
newlist=[['24,4,17,46,0,43'], ['11,43,17'], ['33,17,43,4'], ['74,21'],['21,43,43,74,68,21']]
mylist = list(map(lambda x : list(map(int, x[0].split(','))) , newlist))
print(mylist)
```

Python 2:

```
newlist=[['24,4,17,46,0,43'], ['11,43,17'], ['33,17,43,4'], ['74,21'],['21,43,43,74,68,21']]
mylist = map(lambda x : map(int, x[0].split(',')) , newlist)
print mylist
```